Remove parentheses in "(1)" from hyperlink
Consider the following code:
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{(\arabic{footnote})}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\footnote{}

\end{document}


I'd like to only make the number 1, not the parentheses () red (i.e. a hyperlink). How do I do this? A similar mechanism exists with label=... and ref=... in enumitem.

how do you want to reference a footnote? So what \ref{fn:note} should give? And how should the number in the footnote itself look like?

@UlrikeFischer \ref{fn:note} should just give 1 (explicit formatting can be done with other tools like cleveref). The number in the footnote, however, should always be (1), in text as well as at the bottom of the page.

Well then you shouldn't redefine \thefootnote to contain parentheses.

@UlrikeFischer Do you have any suggestions to change the look of the footnote without changing \thefootnote?

The idea is to simply redefine \footnote and \@makefntext for the bottom text.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% From latex.ltx
\def\footnote{\@ifnextchar[\@xfootnote{\stepcounter\@mpfn
     \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
     \textsuperscript{\normalfont(}\@footnotemark\textsuperscript{\normalfont)}\@footnotetext}}
% From article.cls
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\textsuperscript{\normalfont(}\@makefnmark\textsuperscript{\normalfont)}}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\footnote{}

\end{document}

In text:

At the bottom of the page:

